# Lubuntu freezes

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

The last 5-6 days I have a problem with my lubuntu (14.04.03 LTS). It freezes without any reason. I mean, CPU runs on 38 °C and my motherboard runs on 34-35 °C. And my voltage values are:

CPU Vcore: 1.2~
3.3V: 3.4~
5V: 5.2~
12V: 12.056~

But I noticed something, it usually freezes when I watch videos or listen to music on youtube. When it freezes, it freezes completely. I can't use my mouse, keyboard etc. and the sound freezes too. The only solution is to reboot.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Is there any way we can assist? Is there also a question you forgot to ask?

Comment: The question is so simple. What can I do to stop this freezing thing? Why my lubuntu does this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Could be GPU related, since both watching videos and listening to music videos (if there are a lot of animations) makes the GPU work hard, especially if the driver is not a recent one. Also sometimes, if you have a hybrid graphic adapter setup, choosing the "power save mode" should enable the "stable" adapter. But you haven't told us yet about the specs of your computer, which would let us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Well, my GPU isn't so good but it isn't so bad too. Here are my specs:

Intel Q8400 2.60 GHZ Quad Core
Nvidia GT 220
3 GB DDR2 800 Mhz RAM

Comment: `lspci -vvnn | grep VGA` **and** `cat /var/log/dmesg | grep -i nvidia` - please paste into a pastebin

Comment: I did it. What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Are you on LAN or WLAN?

Comment: I am currently on LAN.

Comment: It's hard to tell, could be one or several issues... could be something like: **"...radiator on my chipset has detached"** - [link]http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661035. Or have a look here:
[link]https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze